# How to stop sink from dripping/leaking?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I was trying to put in the plug mechanism for the bathroom sink.  I actually turned the entire plumbing underneath the sink and I think I broke the seal between the drain hole and the sink.

Now there is a slow leak...just drops.  You can see it in the picture.
[image: drain hole]
[image: slow leak]

What is the best way to stop the leak?  (I think we can fix the drain hole and sink connection/interface)

Answer (score 1):

Plumbers putty. Remove the drain and apply a new string of plumbers putty.

Comment: Will Caulk around the outer edge work instead?

Comment: Kitchen/bathroom caulk could work, won't last long, and won't completely seal. Plumbers putty is cheap, a tub for under $5. Then you just pull the drain pipe up and out, put a string/rope of putty in and squish it back down, tighten and hook everything back up.

Comment: Do as jeff said and use plumbers putty.